# Command-T: Is it possible to have project-specific ignore-patterns?

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

so I read through the documentation and a couple of search-results on google but I can't seem to find a solution for my problem.

I'm using Command-T and set up a "global" ignore pattern in my vimrc:

```
let g:CommandTWildIgnore="**/*.min.*,**/*.jpg,**/*.png,*/dist,*/docs,*/node_modules,*/nginx,*/tmp"
```

This works fine so far.

Now I wanted to add to this global-pattern a project-specific setting so the global one wouldn't get too long.

For example I have set up something similiar for AG where I have a "global" .agignore-file in my vimrc-folder and then a project-specific .agignore-file in the project-folder.

Is this possible with Command-T too? I know I can add to the global-pattern using the vim-commandline but this only lasts until I close vim. I would like a similiar setup to AG but I don't **know where to put** the command or **how to name** the file.

Any ideas? :)

Greetings.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is possible with stand alone command-T, but a workaround might be the use of this plugin:
http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1860

It allows you to define project-specific vim settings, so you could use it to override or add to your command-T ignore cases.

Or perhaps an eaiser way, for each project add something like this to your .vimrc:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead /path/to/project/* let g:CommandTWildIgnore="..."
```